# node JS unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, request, token

I have to get a token from a server someone set up but when I try to get it I get "Error: unable to verify the first certificate".
I browsed the web for answers and found somethings about globalAgent but I don't know how to implement it in my code. Some help would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: 'NEEDED_URL',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-from-urlencoded'},
    data: {
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
        client_secret: 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
        scope: 'YOUR_SCOPE'
    }
  };

  function callback(error, body) {
    if (!error) {
      console.log(body);
    }

    else {
      console.log("error: " + error);
    }
  }

  request(options, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS uses its own trust store, separate to that of the operating system.
Some servers use a root certificate that NodeJS does not trust, in which case you need to set up a NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS environment variable, and add the public key of the certificate issuer.

As an example, my MacOS system has a line like this in the .zprofile file, representing a certificate bundle:

```
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/Users/gary/certs/trusted.ca.pem
```

The file itself looks like this (shortened for clarity). This should only be needed when using one of these is in effect:

- You are using self signed certificates
- You are using an HTTP proxy to view decrypted HTTPS traffic
- You are using a certificate issued by your company
- Your company uses a corporate SSL firewall filter that replaces the root certificate of the target site

More info in my blog post on [Developer SSL Trust Troubleshooting](https://authguidance.com/2017/11/11/developer-ssl-setup/).

[image]